# Salesforce Connected App - Push Messaging Android GCM API Key

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, connected-apps, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

I am trying to enable the push messaging in a connected app. Can someone explain me what is this `API Key` and how do I get the `androidPushNotificationClientId`?

[image]

API Key - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_create_connected_app_android.htm

androidPushNotificationClientId - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_client_app_hybrid.htm

Answer (score 3):

This is the GCM key.

1) Go to this [URL](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/googlecloudmessaging/overview?project=fanfies-982)

2) Click `Enable API`

[image]

3) Click `Credentials` -> `New Credentials` and then chose `Android Key`

[image]

4) You will then the key as shown

[image]